# Magento Timezone Wrong

Tags: magento-1.9, timezone, datetime

I can't seem to work out whats going on with my Magento timezones.
All my orders in the backend are processed correctly and have the correct times. The backend reports however are out by 13hrs. I've tried all solutions that I've found without any success. For example any order processed at 11am will show in the reports as if it was ordered at 10pm . Which actually wont show up on the reports untill that time rolls over.

I've edited core fields Locale.php, mage.php, and config.xml to reflect the correct timezone and my server and magento are set to the correct time zone: NZDT = UTC +13hrs.

I've also seen in the email queue table in phpmyadmin show the created at date which is correct and a processed at date which is seems to save as UTC time not my locale time. This leads me to believe all the orders also are processed in UTC time for report output?? [image]

Does anyone know how the reports process dates or how I can edit this to reflect the correct timezone?